# php won't insert data into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, insert

Today i have run into some problems with mysql, php and html.

So i have a database called "gebruikers" in that database i have a table called "registratie" and i use USBwebserver V8.6 for the hosting

i have made a form for people to register them for the website i am planning to make, but what i'm bumping into is that when i press "inschrijven" it won't insert the data typed in the form into my database i have looked on stackoverflow but i couldn't find the solving answer to my problem.

PHP:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$gebruikersnaam = mysql_real_escape_string($post['gebruikersnaam']);
$wachtwoord = mysql_real_escape_string($post['wachtwoord']);
$voornaam = mysql_real_escape_string($post['voornaam']);
$tussenvoegsel = mysql_real_escape_string($post['tussenvoegsel']);
$achternaam = mysql_real_escape_string($post['achternaam']);
$klas = mysql_real_escape_string($post['klas']);
$telefoon = mysql_real_escape_string($spot['telefoon']);
$geboortedatum = mysql_real_escape_string($post['geboortedatum']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($post['email']);
$geslacht = mysql_real_escape_string($post['geslacht']);

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO gebruikers(gebruikersnaam,) VALUES('$gebruikersnaam')"
?>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id=titel>
        <a href=index.html><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Homepage"id=logo></a>
    Registratie
    </div>

    <div id=registratie>
        form  method="post">
        Gebruikersnaam:
        <input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam">
        <br>
        <br>
        Wachtwoord:
        <input type="password" name="wachtwoord">
        <br>
        <br>
        Voornaam:
        <input type="text" name="voornaam">
        <br>
        <br>
        Tussenvoegsel:
        <input type="text"name="tussenvoegsel">
        <br>
        <br>
        Achternaam:
        <input type="text" name="achternaam">
        <br>
        <br>
        Klas:
        <input type="text" name="klas">
        <br>
        <br>
        Telefoon:
        <input type="tel" name="telefoon">
        <br>
        <br>
        Geboortedatum:
        <input type="date" name="geboortedatum">
        <br>
        <br>
        Email:
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <br>
        <br>
        Geslacht:
        <br>
        <select>
        <option value="Man">Man</option>
        <option value="Vrouw">Vrouw</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="alert('Registratie voltooid')" value="Inschrijven">
        </form>

        <a href=index.html id="button">Terug naar hoofdpagina</a>
        </div>

</body>
```

i really hope that this can help you guys out.
this is my DBCONNECT.PHP:

```
    <?php
if(!mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "gebruikers"))
{
    die('connection problem.' .mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_select_db("gebruikers"))
{
    die('No database selected' .mysql_error());
}
include 
?>
```

i really hope you guys could help me out, because i'm out of ideas how i can fix this problem and i don't know where my problem lies.

NOTE: some words are in dutch.

Comment: remove **,** in insert query

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: You're testing to see if there are any errors when you connect to the database, but you aren't doing that when you try to run the query. Don't you think it might be useful to?

Comment: deprecated functions again! Grrrr

Comment: yea, i am a complete rookie at this so, i looked at your modern replacement but honestly i did not saw the difference

Answer (score 0):

You having mistake here

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO gebruikers(gebruikersnaam,) VALUES('$gebruikersnaam')"
```

It should be like

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO gebruikers(gebruikersnaam) VALUES('$gebruikersnaam')")){
    // if true do some stuff if you need
}
?>
```

so in your query you have extra comma (,) then missing closing brackets and at the end you missing if brackets if you need to do some operations in it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO gebruikers(gebruikersnaam,) VALUES('$gebruikersnaam')"
```

to

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO gebruikers(gebruikersnaam,) VALUES('$gebruikersnaam')") or die(mysql_error());
    if($insert){
        //do your stuff
    }
```

Comment: in the if ($insert) must i put my PHP code to insert into the database?

Comment: No,on the if($insert){} you put anything you want after the insert on the database, the $insert=mysql_query....already inserts to the DB...done

Answer (score 0):

You having mistake here

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO gebruikers(gebruikersnaam,)
VALUES('$gebruikersnaam')"
```

It should be like

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO gebruikers(gebruikersnaam)
VALUES('$gebruikersnaam')"){}
?>
```

i've replaced my code with yours, but it still won't insert the data i typed in the form into the database, thanks for thinking with me. appreciating

Comment: 2 closing bracket needed. you have only one

Comment: yea sorry i'm a complete rookie at this, i have used your code now instead of mine is it then correct?

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the POST variables correctly.

```
 $gebruikersnaam = mysql_real_escape_string($post['gebruikersnaam']);
```

Should be:

```
$gebruikersnaam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
```

Also, [it's a bad habit to throw die() functions for minor things](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php#109834) like database handling since this kills the rest of the page's functionality.

Comment: Whenever queries don't work you could try inputting raw SQL to the database to see if the SQL syntax is not broken. Also, when using variables in them it's good to check if the variables are defined correctly by echoing them before the query statement (although this would be hard if you run into a die() before getting to that echo)